# Make RegEx groups to split line into columns

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I've been having trouble with some comma based RegEx creation. In the following structure the first 19 columns should be split only by commas, the next 3 columns have `{ }` but inside these brackets I can have more brackets (it's a "script block"). So for the last 3 I want to have everything inside `,{}`

This is the structure

```
ID,AegisName,Name,Type,Buy,Sell,Weight,ATK[:MATK],DEF,Range,Slots,Job,Class,Gender,Loc,wLV,eLV[:maxLevel],Refineable,View,{ Script },{ OnEquip_Script },{ OnUnequip_Script }
```

With this for example

```
1624,Lich_Bone_Wand,Lich's Bone Wand,5,20,,800,60:170,,1,2,0x00018314,18,2,2,3,70,1,10,{ bonus bInt,1; bonus bDex,1; bonus bAtkEle,Ele_Undead; .@r = getrefine(); bonus3 bAutoSpellWhenHit,"NPC_WIDECURSE",5,10+.@r; if(.@r>=9){ bonus bMatkRate,3; bonus bMaxSP,300; } },{},{}
```

I've found this `([^\,]*),"x(19)."(\{.*\}),"x(2)."(\{.*\})` but it's in Perl and I couldn't translate to JavaScript. I can see that if I combine `(\{.*\})` three times (like this `(\{.*\}),(\{.*\}),(\{.*\})`, it will get me the last 3 columns and this `([^\,]*),` will get me the first columns split correctly but also interfere with the last ones and so I tried "limiting" it to the first 19 occurences but if I do `([^\,]*),{19}` it won't work

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Regex probably can't parse this if the script blocks have arbitrary code in them. A custom parser seems necessary.

Comment: fyi that _Perl_ thing not do noting. number 2 JS not do recursion in regex! --!> `have { } but inside these brackets I can have more brackets` requires _balance_ brakets. as well cant parse lang syntax using balance yes ? quotes, commnts, stuff hide obvuscert

Comment: If your data is proper CSV format (which your example is not), you can use a CSV parser, such as: https://github.com/peterthoeny/parse-csv-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to accomplish this using a combination of replace & split:

1. temporarily replace commas within `{...}`, split on commas, restore the commas within each array item
2. split on commas, then combine array items from first occurrence of `{` to last occurrence of `}`, keeping track of nesting
3. do a split with negative lookahead to avoid a split on commas within `{...}`

Here is an example for the first option, where we temporarily replace commas within `{...}`:

```
function properSplit(line) {
    return line
    .replace(/(\{[^,]*,.*?\})(?=,)/g, function(m, p1) {
        return p1.replace(/,/g, '\x01');
    })
    .split(/,/)
    .map(function(item) {
        return item.replace(/\x01/g, ',');
    });
}

var str = "1624,Lich_Bone_Wand,Lich's Bone Wand,5,20,,800,60:170,,1,2,0x00018314,18,2,2,3,70,1,10,{ bonus bInt,1; bonus bDex,1; bonus bAtkEle,Ele_Undead; .@r = getrefine(); bonus3 bAutoSpellWhenHit,\"NPC_WIDECURSE\",5,10+.@r; if(.@r>=9){ bonus bMatkRate,3; bonus bMaxSP,300; } },{},{}";
console.log(JSON.stringify(properSplit(str), null, ' '));
```

Output:

```
[
 "1624",
 "Lich_Bone_Wand",
 "Lich's Bone Wand",
 "5",
 "20",
 "",
 "800",
 "60:170",
 "",
 "1",
 "2",
 "0x00018314",
 "18",
 "2",
 "2",
 "3",
 "70",
 "1",
 "10",
 "{ bonus bInt,1; bonus bDex,1; bonus bAtkEle,Ele_Undead; .@r = getrefine(); bonus3 bAutoSpellWhenHit,\"NPC_WIDECURSE\",5,10+.@r; if(.@r>=9){ bonus bMatkRate,3; bonus bMaxSP,300; } }",
 "{}",
 "{}"
]
```

Explanation:

- The first `replace()` replaces commas within `{...}` with a non-printable character `'\x01'`. It scans non-greedily to the next `},` pattern, where the `,` is a positive lookahead
- the `split()` now misses the commas within `{...}`
- the `map()` restored the non-printable chars to commas